How to I turn on USB debugging in android device that don't have any display or screen?
How do I turn on USB debugging in android phone having no any display?
I want to know that is it possible that I can turn on USB debugging or get shell permission of a android device that don't have any display or screen.
I have OPPO F7 and it's hardware is in very good condition (Motherboard) and I want to use it in my some of my  Linux based project and for that first it should be root but it don't have display (it's damaged) and the usb debugging or wifi debugging is turned OFF.
Can someone please tell me is it possible?
I  connect it to my pc with usb cable and I just can access some files and I download the RAT app in the files in but don't know how to install it in the device

For security reasons on stock ROMs adb always have to enabled via developer menu. There is no exception. Only on bootloader unlocked devices you can install a ROM (or modify your existing) so that adb is always active.

You can dispatch touch events with ADB, the solution that reaches my mind is this.

The easiest way is to get test points for UART and solder USB-to-serial adapter to it, like this blog post shows for one of the zillions of Android-based devices: https://andy-shev.dreamwidth.org/152335.html.
